# Sorted Arraylist printing out in wrong order

Tags: java, sorting, printing, arraylist

I have an Arraylist of temperatures and days. and I sorted the arraylist using an insertion sort method.  having when i go to print it out it does not print out in a sorted manner it prints out:76, 84, 81, 88, 87.  Could it be because I commented out the Collections.sort(dailytemps) line? it was erroring out so I commented it out

Here is my code:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DailyTemperature 
    {

    //variables
    private double temperature;
    private String day;

    //getTemp & setTemp methods
    public double getTemp()
    {
      return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemp(double newTemp)
    {
      temperature = newTemp;
    }

    //getDay & setDay methods
    public String getDay()
    {
      return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String newDay)
    {
      day = newDay;
    }

    //constructor
  public DailyTemperature(String day, double temperature)
  {
    this.day = day;
    this.temperature = temperature;
  }

  //compareTo method used for Comparable interface
  public int compareTo(DailyTemperature other)
  {
    if (temperature < other.temperature) return -1;
    if (temperature == other.temperature) return 0;
    return -1;
  }


  //toString method to print out original arraylist contents and sorted arraylist contentes
  public String toString()
  {
    return("Day of Week: " + this.getDay() +
           " - Temperature: " + this.getTemp());
  }
}



import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DailyTemperatureList
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps = new ArrayList<DailyTemperature>();

    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Mon", 87.1));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Tue", 88.3));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Wed", 81.2));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Thu", 84.0));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Fri", 76.3));

    //original list printout
    System.out.println("Original List:" );
    System.out.println( dailytemps.toString() );
    System.out.println(" "); //empty line

    //method to sort array list
    insertionSort(dailytemps);
    //sorted list printout
    System.out.println("Sorted List:" );
    System.out.println( dailytemps.toString() );

    //Collections.sort(dailytemps);
  }

  static void insertionSort(ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps)
  {
    DailyTemperature temp = null;
    int position = 0;

    //loop from 2nd element on
    for (int i = 1; i < dailytemps.size(); i++)
    {
      temp = dailytemps.get(i);
      position = i;

      while ( 0 < position && temp.compareTo(dailytemps.get(position - 1)) < 0)
      {
        dailytemps.set(position, dailytemps.get(position - 1));
        position--;
      }
      dailytemps.set(position,temp);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `compareTo()` implementation is incorrect. You never return 1 if `this.temperature` is greater than `other.temparature`.

```
  public int compareTo(DailyTemperature other)
  {
    if (temperature < other.temperature) return -1;
    if (temperature == other.temperature) return 0;
    return -1; // return 1; here
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I was copying over from my computer to our school account and typed -1 instead of 1. Just one more question.  in the DailyTemperature class do i have to implement Comparable<DailyTemperature> ? Because it works without it.

Comment: You ideally should implement `Comparable<DailyTemperature>`. You'd get an exception if you try `Collections.sort()` without it. The class should ideally be ready to be used with `Collections` API as well as sorted collections like a `TreeSet`.

Comment: You don't _need_ to implement `Comparable` because you are using a custom sort and access the `compareTo` method directly. If you wanted to use `Collections.sort` for example you would have to use `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1):

Your commented `Collections.sort` is anyways after print lines. You can simply do `Collections.sort` and then print instead of making a new method insertionSort

Comment: Yes.  But to do this, the declaration of `DailyTemperature` needs to include `implements Comparable<DailyTemperature>`.  This is exactly the advice I gave the OP on an earlier version of this question.